# Get an interface (event) type from its string value

Tags: c#, masstransit

A bit of background first. I am using MassTransit and want to connect endpoints dynamically while not duplicating logic much for building some tests suite. What I am trying is to avoid creating interim consumer classes as they can grow in number over time and use event handler as an anonymous/ temporary consumer. Also, I should be able to perform some assertions on the consumed message.

This is what I have to connect endpoints.

I am wondering if there is a way in C# that would let me use the `string messageType` to determine its corresponding type (interface as recommended in MassTransit) and replace it in the places of `SubmitOrderRequestFailed`...

```cs
public async Task ConnectEndpointAsync(string messageType)
{
    Type type = Type.GetType(eventType);                       // <-- Not working
    var handle = Bus.ConnectReceiveEndpoint(
            $"SubmitOrderRequestFailed_{DateTime.Now.Ticks}",
            e => e.Handler<SubmitOrderRequestFailed>(async context =>
            {
                Reason = context.Message.Reason;//local variable
                await TcsRequestResolved.Task;//local variable
            }));
    await handle.Ready;
}
```

In my constructor, I have

```cs
    Bus = MassTransit.Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(config =>
    {
                config.Host(_connectionString);
    });
```

...for example, if I call `ConnectEndpointAsync( messageType: "InventoryUpdateRequestFailed" )` I want to create the handler for  that message type (`InventoryUpdateRequestFailed`) instead of `SubmitOrderRequestFailed`.

Any advice would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: type.gettype requires a fully qualified class name, ie it must include the namespace

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but there are a few significant issues in your code you should fix: for example, you should be using `DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks` instead of `DateTime.Now.Ticks` for 
geography-invariant monotonically increasing timestamp values.

Comment: Where are your `messageType` strings coming from? Where are your MassTransit message classes/interfaces defined?

Comment: Why not make `ConnectEndpointAsync` a generic method, like `Task ConnectEndpointAsync<TMessage>() where TMessage : class, IMessage`  so you'd call it like `ConnectEndpointAsync<InventoryUpdateRequestFailed>()` and `ConnectEndpointAsync<SubmitOrderRequestFailed>()` ? (where `interface IMessage` is some interface you'd define to allow access to `context.Message.Reason`).

Comment: You should be able to achive your goal with reflection. But in the right types then you can create types and invoke methods.

Comment: Dai's suggestion helped me write some generic methods. Thank you.